# A more pythonic approach to the following algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I change the final structure by a more logical:

```
{'state1': {'city1': ['dict1', 'dict2']}, 'state2': {'City2': ['dict3']}}
```

and the code:

```
dir_dict = {}
for one in objects:
    state = one.dir.city.state.name
    city ​​= one.dir.city.name
    address = one.dir.address
    if state not in dir_dict:
        dir_dict[state] = {}
    if city not in dir_dict[state]:
        dir_dict[state][city] = []
    dir_dict[state][city].append(address)
```

I still implement code @ Eric

Comment: Can you show some sample input and output?

Comment: why are you setting `dir_dict [x.direction.city.state.name]` twice?

Comment: @Inbar: To set it, and then "uniqueify" it. Seems reasonable, if a bit verbose.

Comment: Your list format `[{'state1': ['city1', 'City2,]}, {' state2 ': [' city3 ',' city4 ']}]` makes no sense. Why not a dictionary? `{'state1': ['city1', 'City2'], 'state2': [' city3 ',' city4 ']}`.

Comment: @Eric But it doesn't "uniquefy" because the list will always have only a single element whenever it reaches that statement.

Comment: @NullUserException: True, but that's a different problem. (could be an indentation problem)

Comment: You are right @Eric I change to: {'state1':{'city1':['dir1', 'dir2']}....}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
dir_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))
for x in objects:
     dir_dict[x.state][x.city].add(x.address)

dir_list = dir_dict.keys()
```